# Program exits unexpectedly without error

Tags: java, wss4j

I faced strange behaviour - WSSecSignature (part of wss4j lib) performs

```
  c14nMethod = signatureFactory.newCanonicalizationMethod(canonAlgo, c14nSpec); //last
  } catch (Exception ex) {
  log.error("", ex);
  throw new WSSecurityException(
  WSSecurityException.FAILED_SIGNATURE, "noXMLSig", null, ex
  );
 }
```

and exits without any exceptions/notifications. The line marked with "last" is the last executed (I see it with debug), program doesn't enter catch block nor performs the line after it, just exits. I don't own code of current signatureFactory implementation, just jars.
Could someone provide thoughts on realistic scenarios why it can behave this way (the only thing I can think of - the class for some reason calls smth like system.exit() without even writing a message in log but I cannot imagine the reason to write such code).

Comment: I think your last sentence is correct (and no, I can't think why someone would do it either). Does `echo $?` give a non-zero value?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. I executed the program in eclipse and in its console I don't see anything related to exit (though logs even INFO level do appear there).

Comment: Well, I found it - eclipse debug shows "exit value:0"

Comment: I guess it is throwing a RuntimeException...turn logging to FINE/DEBUG and see what it says.